# Update a manual copy with git

Tags: git

I have a git repo with an updated application, but there's also an isntance which was developed in the "pre-git" era: it's a manual copy with no `.git` folder there.

I'd like to update the copy and ensure any changes that might be there are saved. How?

The easiest is to do `git clone` to another folder, then copy the instance over the working tree and observe `git diff`. Any better ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do a `git init` and link the repository (with a `git remote add`), then copy the files in manually. Git should recognize them. Doing a `git status` should show you what has changed.

Comment: Just for your info `git remote add` doesn't link anything.

Comment: `init` + `remote add` is the right thing to do, but then I need git to get the recent commits w/o touching the working tree. That would have been a win! :)